# Shopify Liquid: Hamburger menu won't open on click

Tags: shopify, header-files, hamburger-menu

Aboslutely frankenstein bit of code here that I've taken from other pages and tried to roll into a header.

In console i can see that the nav part runs and generates the nav links but the menu doesn't open on click

I want the navbar on the left to open on click, I've just lifted code from another header in the theme but something gone wrong.

Site preview can be seen here: https://7qpu98yp36za6fbf-53393555651.shopifypreview.com

code is below:

`

```
<style>

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #4ea7f5;
  border-bottom: 1px inset;
  border-bottom-color: #fff7de;
}

  
.header__logo {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-width: 8vw;
}
  
.header__menu {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

.header svg {
  color: #fff7de;
}
  
.header__menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.header__menu-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.header__nav {
  display: none;
}

.header__cart {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.header__cart-link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__cart-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__cart-count {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__cart-total {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>

<header class="header">
  
  <div class="header__menu">

      
  {% unless linklists[section.settings.main_linklist] == blank %}
            <button type="button" class="btn--link site-header__icon site-header__menu js-mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav--open" aria-controls="MobileNav"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t }}">
              {% include 'icon-hamburger' %}
              {% include 'icon-close' %}
            </button>
 {% endunless %} 
        
      
      </div>
    

    <nav class="mobile-nav-wrapper medium-up--hide critical-hidden" role="navigation">
      <ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav">
        {% for link in linklists[section.settings.main_linklist].links %}
          {%- assign outerLoopIndex = forloop.index -%}

          <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
            {% if link.links != blank %}
              {% capture child_list_handle %}{{ link.handle }}-{{ outerLoopIndex }}{% endcapture %}
              <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link{% if link.child_active %} mobile-nav__link--active{% endif %}" data-target="{{ child_list_handle }}" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
                <div class="mobile-nav__icon">
                  {% include 'icon-chevron-right' %}
                </div>
              </button>
              <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-parent="{{ child_list_handle }}" data-level="2">
                <li class="visually-hidden" tabindex="-1" data-menu-title="2">
                  {{- link.title }} {{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t -}}
                </li>
                <li class="mobile-nav__item border-bottom">
                  <div class="mobile-nav__table">
                    <div class="mobile-nav__table-cell mobile-nav__return">
                      <button class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__return-btn" type="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="{{ link.title }}">
                        {% include 'icon-chevron-left' %}
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <span class="mobile-nav__sublist-link mobile-nav__sublist-header mobile-nav__sublist-header--main-nav-parent">
                      <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>

                {% for childlink in link.links %}
                  <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
                    {% if childlink.links != blank %}
                      {% capture grandchild_list_handle %}{{ childlink.handle }}-{{ outerLoopIndex }}-{{ forloop.index }}{% endcapture %}
                      <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link mobile-nav__sublist-link" data-target="{{ grandchild_list_handle }}" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                        <div class="mobile-nav__icon">
                          {% include 'icon-chevron-right' %}
                        </div>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-parent="{{ grandchild_list_handle }}" data-level="3">
                        <li class="visually-hidden" tabindex="-1" data-menu-title="3">
                          {{- childlink.title }} {{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t -}}
                        </li>
                        <li class="mobile-nav__item border-bottom">
                          <div class="mobile-nav__table">
                            <div class="mobile-nav__table-cell mobile-nav__return">
                              <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__return-btn" data-target="{{ child_list_handle }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="{{ childlink.title }}">
                                {% include 'icon-chevron-left' %}
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
                              class="mobile-nav__sublist-link mobile-nav__sublist-header"
                              {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                            >
                              <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        {% for grandchildlink in childlink.links %}
                          <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
                            <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}"
                              class="mobile-nav__sublist-link"
                              {% if grandchildlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                            >
                              <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}</span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                    {% else %}
                      <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
                        class="mobile-nav__sublist-link"
                        {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                      >
                        <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                      </a>
                    {% endif %}
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% else %}
              <a href="{{ link.url }}"
                class="mobile-nav__link{% if link.active %} mobile-nav__link--active{% endif %}"
                {% if link.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
              >
                <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
              </a>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>

    
  <div class="header__logo">
    <div class="logo-container">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/9355/5651/files/Asset_3_6065fdaa-7b36-4775-85fd-e72fd381d130.svg?v=1683146506" >
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<div class="header__cart">

          <a href="{{ routes.cart_url }}" class="site-header__icon site-header__cart">
            <img class="icon icon-cart" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/9355/5651/files/Cart.svg?v=1624717162"/>
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
            <div id="CartCount" class="site-header__cart-count{% if cart.item_count == 0 %} hide{% endif %} critical-hidden" data-cart-count-bubble>
              <span data-cart-count>{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
              <span class="icon__fallback-text medium-up--hide">{{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-total" data-cart-subtotal>£{{cart.total_price | divided_by:100}}</span>
          </a>
      
</div>

  
</header>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "cs": "Záhlaví",
    "da": "Overskrift",
    "de": "Titel",
    "en": "Header",
    "es": "Encabezado",
    "fi": "Ylätunniste",
    "fr": "En-tête",
    "it": "Header",
    "ja": "ヘッダー",
    "ko": "헤더",
    "nb": "Header",
    "nl": "Koptekst",
    "pl": "Nagłówek",
    "pt-BR": "Cabeçalho",
    "pt-PT": "Cabeçalho",
    "sv": "Rubrik",
    "th": "ส่วนหัว",
    "tr": "Üstbilgi",
    "vi": "Đầu trang",
    "zh-CN": "标头",
    "zh-TW": "標頭"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "id": "align_logo",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Zarovnání loga",
        "da": "Logojustering",
        "de": "Logo-Ausrichtung",
        "en": "Logo alignment",
        "es": "Alineación de logo",
        "fi": "Logon tasaus",
        "fr": "Alignement du logo",
        "it": "Allineamento logo",
        "ja": "ロゴアラインメント",
        "ko": "로고 정렬",
        "nb": "Logojustering",
        "nl": "Logo-uitlijning",
        "pl": "Wyrównanie logo",
        "pt-BR": "Alinhamento do logotipo",
        "pt-PT": "Alinhamento do logótipo",
        "sv": "Logojustering",
        "th": "การจัดวางโลโก้",
        "tr": "Logo hizalaması",
        "vi": "Căn chỉnh logo",
        "zh-CN": "logo 对齐方式",
        "zh-TW": "商標對齊"
      },
      "default": "left",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": {
            "cs": "Doleva",
            "da": "Venstre",
            "de": "Links",
            "en": "Left",
            "es": "Izquierda",
            "fi": "Vasen",
            "fr": "Gauche",
            "it": "Sinistra",
            "ja": "左",
            "ko": "왼쪽",
            "nb": "Venstre",
            "nl": "Links",
            "pl": "Do lewej",
            "pt-BR": "Esquerda",
            "pt-PT": "Esquerda",
            "sv": "Vänster",
            "th": "ด้านซ้าย",
            "tr": "Sol",
            "vi": "Bên trái",
            "zh-CN": "左侧",
            "zh-TW": "左方"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": {
            "cs": "Na střed",
            "da": "Centreret",
            "de": "Mittig",
            "en": "Centered",
            "es": "Centrada",
            "fi": "Keskitetty",
            "fr": "Centré",
            "it": "Centrato",
            "ja": "中央揃え",
            "ko": "센터 맞추기",
            "nb": "Sentrert",
            "nl": "Gecentreerd",
            "pl": "Wyśrodkowane",
            "pt-BR": "Centralizado",
            "pt-PT": "Centrado",
            "sv": "Centrera",
            "th": "ตรงกลาง",
            "tr": "Orta",
            "vi": "Giữa",
            "zh-CN": "居中",
            "zh-TW": "置中"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "logo",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Obrázek loga",
        "da": "Logobillede",
        "de": "Logo-Foto",
        "en": "Logo image",
        "es": "Logo",
        "fi": "Logokuva",
        "fr": "Image du logo",
        "it": "Immagine del logo",
        "ja": "ロゴ画像",
        "ko": "로고 이미지",
        "nb": "Logobilde",
        "nl": "Afbeelding van logo",
        "pl": "Obraz logo",
        "pt-BR": "Imagem do logotipo",
        "pt-PT": "Imagem do logótipo",
        "sv": "Logobild",
        "th": "รูปภาพโลโก้",
        "tr": "Logo görseli",
        "vi": "Hình ảnh logo",
        "zh-CN": "logo 图片",
        "zh-TW": "標誌圖片"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "logo_max_width",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Šířka vlastního loga",
        "da": "Tilpasset logobredde",
        "de": "Logobreite",
        "en": "Custom logo width",
        "es": "Ancho del logo personalizado",
        "fi": "Mukautetun logon leveys",
        "fr": "Largeur personnalisée du logo",
        "it": "Larghezza logo personalizzato",
        "ja": "ロゴの幅をカスタマイズする",
        "ko": "사용자 지정 로고 폭",
        "nb": "Tilpasset logobredde",
        "nl": "Aangepaste logo-breedte",
        "pl": "Niestandardowa szerokość logo",
        "pt-BR": "Largura do logotipo personalizado",
        "pt-PT": "Largura de logótipo personalizada",
        "sv": "Anpassad logotypsbredd",
        "th": "ความกว้างของโลโก้แบบกำหนดเอง",
        "tr": "Özel logo genişliği",
        "vi": "Chiều rộng logo tùy chỉnh",
        "zh-CN": "自定义 logo 宽度",
        "zh-TW": "自訂商標寬度"
      },
      "min": 50,
      "max": 250,
      "step": 5,
      "unit": "px",
      "default": 100
    },
    {
      "type": "link_list",
      "id": "main_linklist",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Nabídka",
        "da": "Menu",
        "de": "Menü",
        "en": "Menu",
        "es": "Menú",
        "fi": "Valikko",
        "fr": "Menu",
        "it": "Menu",
        "ja": "メニュー",
        "ko": "메뉴",
        "nb": "Meny",
        "nl": "Menu",
        "pl": "Menu",
        "pt-BR": "Menu",
        "pt-PT": "Menu",
        "sv": "Meny",
        "th": "เมนู",
        "tr": "Menü",
        "vi": "Menu",
        "zh-CN": "菜单",
        "zh-TW": "選單"
      },
      "default": "main-menu"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": {
        "cs": "Panel oznámení",
        "da": "Meddelelseslinje",
        "de": "Ankündigungsbereich",
        "en": "Announcement bar",
        "es": "Barra de anuncios",
        "fi": "Ilmoituspalkki",
        "fr": "Barre d'annonces",
        "it": "Barra degli annunci",
        "ja": "告知バー",
        "ko": "공지 표시줄",
        "nb": "Kunngjøringslinje",
        "nl": "Aankondigingsbalk",
        "pl": "Pasek ogłoszeń",
        "pt-BR": "Barra de avisos",
        "pt-PT": "Barra de comunicado",
        "sv": "Meddelandefält",
        "th": "แถบประกาศ",
        "tr": "Duyuru çubuğu",
        "vi": "Thanh thông báo",
        "zh-CN": "公告栏",
        "zh-TW": "公告列"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "message",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Zobrazit oznámení",
        "da": "Vis meddelelse",
        "de": "Ankündigung anzeigen",
        "en": "Show announcement",
        "es": "Mostrar anuncio",
        "fi": "Näytä ilmoitus",
        "fr": "Afficher l'annonce",
        "it": "Mostra annuncio",
        "ja": "告知を表示する",
        "ko": "공지 표시",
        "nb": "Vis kunngjøring",
        "nl": "Aankondiging weergeven",
        "pl": "Pokaż ogłoszenie",
        "pt-BR": "Exibir comunicado",
        "pt-PT": "Mostrar comunicado",
        "sv": "Visa tillkännagivande",
        "th": "แสดงประกาศ",
        "tr": "Duyuruyu göster",
        "vi": "Hiển thị thông báo",
        "zh-CN": "显示公告",
        "zh-TW": "顯示公告"
      },
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "home_page_only",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Jen domovská stránka",
        "da": "Kun startside",
        "de": "Nur Startseite",
        "en": "Home page only",
        "es": "Solo página de inicio",
        "fi": "Vain etusivu",
        "fr": "Page d'accueil uniquement",
        "it": "Solo home page",
        "ja": "ホームページのみ",
        "ko": "홈페이지만",
        "nb": "Kun på startsiden",
        "nl": "Alleen homepage",
        "pl": "Tylko strona główna",
        "pt-BR": "Apenas na página inicial",
        "pt-PT": "Apenas a página inicial",
        "sv": "Endast hemsida",
        "th": "หน้าแรกเท่านั้น",
        "tr": "Yalnızca ana sayfa",
        "vi": "Chỉ trang chủ",
        "zh-CN": "仅主页",
        "zh-TW": "僅限首頁"
      },
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "message_text",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Text",
        "da": "Tekst",
        "de": "Text",
        "en": "Text",
        "es": "Texto",
        "fi": "Teksti",
        "fr": "Texte",
        "it": "Testo",
        "ja": "テキスト",
        "ko": "텍스트",
        "nb": "Tekst",
        "nl": "Tekst",
        "pl": "Tekst",
        "pt-BR": "Texto",
        "pt-PT": "Texto",
        "sv": "Text",
        "th": "ข้อความ",
        "tr": "Metin",
        "vi": "Văn bản",
        "zh-CN": "文本",
        "zh-TW": "文字"
      },
      "default": {
        "cs": "Tady můžete zadat oznámení",
        "da": "Meddel noget her",
        "de": "Hier etwas ankündigen",
        "en": "Announce something here",
        "es": "Anuncia algo aquí",
        "fi": "Ilmoita jotakin tässä",
        "fr": "Annoncez quelque chose ici",
        "it": "Annuncia qualcosa qui",
        "ja": "ここで告知してください",
        "ko": "여기에 공지하십시오",
        "nb": "Kunngjør noe her",
        "nl": "Kondig hier iets aan",
        "pl": "Ogłoś coś tutaj",
        "pt-BR": "Anuncie algo aqui",
        "pt-PT": "Anunciar algo aqui",
        "sv": "Meddela något här",
        "th": "ประกาศข้อความที่นี่",
        "tr": "Buraya bir duyuru ekleyin",
        "vi": "Thông báo điều gì đó tại đây",
        "zh-CN": "在此处进行公告",
        "zh-TW": "在此公告資訊"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "message_link",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Odkaz",
        "da": "Link",
        "de": "Link",
        "en": "Link",
        "es": "Enlace",
        "fi": "Linkki",
        "fr": "Lien",
        "it": "Link",
        "ja": "リンク",
        "ko": "링크",
        "nb": "Kobling",
        "nl": "Link",
        "pl": "Link",
        "pt-BR": "Link",
        "pt-PT": "Ligação",
        "sv": "Länk",
        "th": "ลิงก์",
        "tr": "Bağlantı",
        "vi": "Liên kết",
        "zh-CN": "链接",
        "zh-TW": "連結"
      },
      "info": {
        "cs": "Volitelné",
        "da": "Valgfri",
        "de": "Optional",
        "en": "Optional",
        "es": "Opcional",
        "fi": "Valinnainen",
        "fr": "Facultatif",
        "it": "Facoltativo",
        "ja": "オプション",
        "ko": "선택 사항",
        "nb": "Valgfritt",
        "nl": "Optioneel",
        "pl": "Opcjonalnie",
        "pt-BR": "Opcional",
        "pt-PT": "Opcional",
        "sv": "Valfritt",
        "th": "ไม่จำเป็น",
        "tr": "İsteğe bağlı",
        "vi": "Không bắt buộc",
        "zh-CN": "可选",
        "zh-TW": "(選填)"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "color_bg",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Panel",
        "da": "Bjælke",
        "de": "Zeile",
        "en": "Bar",
        "es": "Barra",
        "fi": "Palkki",
        "fr": "Barre",
        "it": "Barra",
        "ja": "バー",
        "ko": "바",
        "nb": "Felt",
        "nl": "Balk",
        "pl": "Pasek",
        "pt-BR": "Barra",
        "pt-PT": "Barra",
        "sv": "Fält",
        "th": "แถบ",
        "tr": "Çubuk",
        "vi": "Thanh",
        "zh-CN": "栏",
        "zh-TW": "橫條"
      },
      "default": "#3a3a3a"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "color_text",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Text",
        "da": "Tekst",
        "de": "Text",
        "en": "Text",
        "es": "Texto",
        "fi": "Teksti",
        "fr": "Texte",
        "it": "Testo",
        "ja": "テキスト",
        "ko": "텍스트",
        "nb": "Tekst",
        "nl": "Tekst",
        "pl": "Tekst",
        "pt-BR": "Texto",
        "pt-PT": "Texto",
        "sv": "Text",
        "th": "ข้อความ",
        "tr": "Metin",
        "vi": "Văn bản",
        "zh-CN": "文本",
        "zh-TW": "文字"
      },
      "default": "#ffffff"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```